# Passive voice misuse

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

I wrote this sentence:

```
Therefore, the copula model has been fitted to the data.
```

However, one online program return me writing issue as "Passive voice misuse". I feel that my sentence is correct. However, I would like to double-check it. Is there is any problem with my sentence? Is there a way to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence looks fine to me (as a statistician) although I might have written a model rather than the model. It is worth bearing in mind that the traditional use of the passive in scientific articles does seem slightly dated and you might prefer to rewrite it as

> Therefore, we fitted the copula model to the data